Does ISO 15765-4 support broadcast messages?(Without request the ecu will response?)
I have a doubt about whether ISO 15765-4 supports broadcast messages or only request-response communication.and explain whether in real scenarios ecu will respond without request? In Iso15765-4 protocol
Im tried with request response it's working and i want to know whether broadcast will support or not

There is something call Functional Addressing, which targets all servers in the network. You might investigate the topic.
Note that your question does not meet stackoverflow guidelines. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask question in a way that is in line with community rules.
